# When using generics, how does the List internally check the types for method calls?

Tags: java, generics

Given this `List<Employee>`:

```
List <Employee> empList=new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

When i tried to add a `Student`:

```
l.add(0,new Student(1,2,3));
```

How does the list resolves this and gives me compilation error?

Comment: What is the error? Can you provide a piece of code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Only the compiler can give you compilation errors.

Comment: i know its stupid, but is student implements or extends employee?

Answer (score 5):

Actually it's not specifically the `List` that does the check, it's the compiler (as you hinted).

The `List` simply provides two pieces of information:

- There is a type `E` with which the type `List` is parameterized:

  ```
  public interface List<E> extends Collection<E>
  ```
- the method `add` accepts an object of type `E`:

  ```
  boolean add(E e);
  ```

If you build a `List<Employee>` then *the compiler* knows that you can't call `add` with anything *except*  and `Employee` and will give a compiler error if you try to.

It should also be noted that there are no such checks *at runtime*! So if you somehow manage to "sneak by" the checks made by the compiler (for example by using [a raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)), then you can do all kinds of wrong things to your `List` and the runtime won't detect the problem (until you try to access the "wrong" type in a non-generic way).

Comment: if you want runtime checks, use this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#checkedCollection(java.util.Collection, java.lang.Class)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>()
```

In the above case, since you've specified that your empList would only contain instances of `Employee`.

It would be the responsibility of the compiler to complain when you would try to add any other instance type that is not an `Employee` or derived from it. This is because, you've provided the compiler with enough information for it to decide during compilation what type of instances have you allowed to be be added to this list. So, the compiler knows that `add()` method would always expect instances of/or derived from `Employee` and not `Student`. Hence the error in your case.

Another interesting result of using generics is when you try to `get()` an element from this list. The compiler at that time also knows that the elements that you're trying to get from the list needs to be of `Employee` class. So, in case you perform an illegal cast (for example *casting the object returned from `get()` to a `Student`*), the compiler would again complain.

The following articles might be of help in understanding this concept:

- [`Generics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html)
- [Generics in the Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf) (*This is a little old but worth a read*)

Comment: Yes exactly my question is how compiler checks it is of type Employee and it is of type Student

Comment: @Sujay: the question was not about how to correct the code, but *how* `List` actually detects the problem.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: If I understand correctly, before the edit was made, the question did not specifically show the usage of `Generics`. My answer was based on correcting the usage :)